# how to access array in async context

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

i have this function :

```
const list = [];

(async () => {

  await fs.readdir(JSON_DIR, async (err, files) => {

    await files.forEach(async filename => {

      const readStream = fs.createReadStream(path.join("output/scheduled", filename));
      const parseStream = json.createParseStream();

      await parseStream.on('data', async (hostlist: HostInfo[]) => {
        hostlist.forEach(async host => {

          list.push(host);

        });
      });

      readStream.pipe(parseStream);
    })
  });
  //here list.length = 0
  console.log(list.length);
})();
```

the function read from a directory of large json files, and reads them, for each file,it create a stream that starts reading the json, and the stream can be working at the same time.
at the end of the function i need to save the variable host in the list, but when i check the lis at the end, is empty.
how can i save the content of the host to a global variable, so it can be accessible in the end.

i tought as solution to check when every file is finished reading using and end event.
though to access the list at the end, i need another event to start when all other events are finished.
and looks complicated.

i have been using the big-json library,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json

Comment: Since you are using async-await, you do not need to use callbacks here.

Comment: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: @pavi2410, i also tried using the syncronous version of the readdir function, but is not working,

Comment: Note that there is no threading in JS. There is only one thread, and then there are workers (for which shared arrays are well documented and an MDN search away). Asynchronous does _not_ mean "parallel", it's _only_ asynchronous (JS will still only ever run one thing at a time).

Comment: See 'fs/promises'. Also note the callback to forEach is synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a counter to determine when the streams have finished processing.
You can use `readdirSync` for executing the operation synchronously.

```
const list: HostInfo[] = [];

(() => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(JSON_DIR);
  
  let streamFinished = 0;
  let streamCount = files.length;

  files.forEach((filename) => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(
      path.join('output/scheduled', filename)
    );
    const parseStream = json.createParseStream();

    parseStream.on('error', (err) => {
      // Handle errors
    })
    parseStream.on('data', (hostlist: HostInfo[]) => {
      list.push(...hostlist);
    });
    parseStream.on('end', () => {
      streamFinished++;
      if (streamFinished === streamCount) {
        // End of all streams...
      }
      console.log(list.length);    
    })

    readStream.pipe(parseStream);
  });
})();
```